# Iterate over a Map

Tags: apex

```
[
  {
    "company_base": {
      "business_type": "Life, Accident, and Health",
      "established_year": 1998,
      "customer_complaint_ratio": 0.001336804425081,
      "default_resources": {
        "final-expense-life": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        },
        "medicare-advantage": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        },
        "medicare-supplement": {
          "e_app_link": "https:\/\/www.unitedhealthproducers.com\/portal\/server.pt"
        },
        "hospital-indemnity": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        },
        "dental": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        }
      },
      "parent_company_base": {
        "established_year": 1998,
        "code": "707",
      },
      "sp_rating": "AA-",
      "naic": "79413",
      "type": "STOCK",
      "name": "UnitedHealthcare Ins Co"
    },
    "has_pdf_app": false,
    "rate": {
      "quarter": 42681,
      "annual": 168324,
      "semi_annual": 85362,
      "month": 14027
    },
    "rating_class": "Standard",
    "fees": [

    ],

    "archive": null,
    "select": false,
    "age_increases": [
      0.0434875597,
      0.0416752067,
      0.0399422837,
      0.0384712412
    ],
    "rate_type": "community rated",
    "note": null,
    "discounts": [
      {
        "type": "percent",
        "name": "household",
        "value": 0.05
      }
    ],
    "location": "aghzfmNzZ2FwaXIVCxIITG9jYXRpb24YgICA2vu9hAsMogEIbWVkX3N1cHA",
    "legacy_id": null,

    "last_modified": "2017-02-08T21:59:00.189200",
    "plan": "F",
    "riders": [

    ],
    "expires_date": "2017-03-31T00:00:00",
    "tobacco": false,
    "has_brochure": false,
    "gender": "M",
    "age": 65
  },
  {
    "company_base": {
      "business_type": "Life, Accident, and Health",
      "established_year": 1998,
      "customer_complaint_ratio": 0.001336804425081,
      "default_resources": {
        "final-expense-life": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        },
        "medicare-advantage": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        },
        "medicare-supplement": {
          "e_app_link": "https:\/\/www.unitedhealthproducers.com\/portal\/server.pt"
        },
        "hospital-indemnity": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        },
        "dental": {
          "e_app_link": ""
        }
      },
      "parent_company_base": {
        "established_year": 1998,
        "code": "707",
      },
      "sp_rating": "AA-",
      "naic": "79413",
      "type": "STOCK",
      "name": "UnitedHealthcare Ins Co"
    },
    "has_pdf_app": false,
    "rate": {
      "quarter": 42681,
      "annual": 168324,
      "semi_annual": 85362,
      "month": 14027
    },
    "rating_class": "Standard",
    "fees": [

    ],

    "archive": null,
    "select": false,
    "age_increases": [
      0.0434875597,
      0.0416752067,
      0.0399422837,
      0.0384712412
    ],
    "rate_type": "community rated",
    "note": null,
    "discounts": [
      {
        "type": "percent",
        "name": "household",
        "value": 0.05
      }
    ],
    "location": "aghzfmNzZ2FwaXIVCxIITG9jYXRpb24YgICA2vu9hAsMogEIbWVkX3N1cHA",
    "legacy_id": null,

    "last_modified": "2017-02-08T21:59:00.189200",
    "plan": "F",
    "riders": [

    ],
    "expires_date": "2017-03-31T00:00:00",
    "tobacco": false,
    "has_brochure": false,
    "gender": "M",
    "age": 65
  }
]
```

hello i get from 3d api data like from the up ,

i need to over and collect some details but how i can loop over the map ( i fount that i need to use it ..)

```
    public List<med_supp> my_list = new List<med_supp>();
    public object data;
    public class discounts{
        String type;
        String name;
        Decimal value;
    }
    public class rate{
        Integer quarter;
        Integer annual;
        Integer semi_annual;
        Integer month;
    }
    public class med_supp{
       Datetime expires_date;
       Boolean tobacco;
       String gender;
       Integer age; 
       String plan;
       List <discounts> discounts;
       List <rate> rate;
       String name;
    }



    public  appspotApiMedSuppController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController ){
        String  requestEndPoint ='https://wwww.google.com?zip5=15963&age=65&gender=M&tobacco=0&select=0&plan=F&effective_date=2017-03-01&offset=0';
        Http http =new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader('x-api-token', 'asdasdasdasdasdasd');
        request.setEndpoint(requestEndPoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        if(response.getStatusCode() ==200){

            Map<String, Object> m =(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());


        }
        else{
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,' There was an error retrieving the data information.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can iterate a map by key or value:

**Key**

```
for (String key : m.keySet())
{
    Object value = m.get(key);
}
```

**Value**

```
for (Object value : m.values())
{
     // logic if you don't need the key
}
```